# Acceder a una función de la clase desde el header en React Native

Tags: react-native

Mi problema es que no puedo acceder desde un botón que tengo en el header a una función de la misma clase.

Me gustaría saber cómo acceder

He hecho dos funciones, una parecida al cambio de pantalla desde el header, pero tratando de acceder a una función en vez de otra pantalla.

Y otra manera sugerida por alguien más que tampoco funciona.

```js
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
        static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerTitle: ('',
                    ...
                ),


                headerLeft: (
                    ...
                ),

                headerRight: (
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this._function() }}>
                        <Image style={{ width: 30, height: 30, marginLeft: 10 }}
                            source={require('./images/reportIcon.png')}
                        />
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                ),
                //Segunda manera
                headerRight: (
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress: () => { navigation.getParam('report') }>
                        <Image style={{ width: 30, height: 30, marginLeft: 10 }}
                            source={require('./images/reportIcon.png')}
                        />
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                )
            }
        }

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                ...
          }
        }

        _function = () => {
            Alert.alert(
                'Titutlo',
                'Blablabla',
                [{ text: 'Entendido' }]
            );
        }
    }
```

La primera manera me manda un error.

La segunda no marca errores pero no da ninguna acción, OJO: tengo la función en ComponentDidMount, pero aún asnillos no funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es normal que no veas que ninguna función haga algo, la primera porque es un método estático, es decir que no tiene una instancia si no que pertenece a la clase, es decir, es incorrecto llamar a `this` cuando defines un método con `static`, lo ideal sería  así `HomeScreen._function()` lo cual quizá no te funcione también del todo bien ya que `_function` si es un método de la instancia, lo ideal sería hacer algo así:

```
const instanceHome = new HomeScreen();  // <= Creamos la instancia
return instanceHome._function();  // <= Llamamos al método
```

O bien convertir `_function` a estática, así:

```
static _function = () {
  Alert.alert(
    'Titutlo',
    'Blablabla',
    [{ text: 'Entendido' }]
  );
}
```

Pero recuerda que dentro de una función que defines con `static` no debes usar `this`.

La segunda opción no hace nada porque no le estás diciendo que haga algo, solo le estás diciendo que ejecute el método `navigation.getParam('report')` pero no estás ni retornando, ni tratando los datos de alguna forma, no estás cambiando nada, ni llamando a ninguna otra función interna, tampoco estás haciendo un log, por eso no notes que suceda algo.

Cualquier inquietud, pregunta